# Why is Identity monad useful?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I often read that

> It seem that identity monad is useless. It's not... but that's another
>   topic.

So can anyone tell my how is it useful?

Comment: I see it as a great tool to explain monads to people with no former knowledge on this kind of stuff and as a valuable exercise for anybody learning how to implement monads.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Identity` is to monads, functors and applicative functors as 0 is to numbers. On its own it seems useless, but it's often needed in places where one expects a monad or an (applicative) functor that actually doesn't do anything.

As already mentioned, `Identity` allows us to define just monad transformers and then define their corresponding monads just as `SomeT Identity`.

But that's not all. It's often convenient to also define other concepts in terms of monads, which usually adds a lot of flexibility. For example [`Conduit i m o`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.4/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:Conduit) (also see [this tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/conduit-overview)) defines an element in a pipeline that can request data of type `i`, can produce data of type `o`, and uses monad `m` for internal processing. Then such a pipeline can be run in the given monad using

```
($$) :: Monad m => Source m a -> Sink a m b -> m b
```

(where `Source` is an alias for `Conduit` with no input and `Sink` for `Conduit` with no output). And when no effectful computations are needed in the pipeline, just pure code, we just specialize `m` to `Identity` and run such a pipeline as

```
runIdentity (source $$ sink)
```

---

`Identity` is also the "empty" functor and applicative functor: `Identity` composed with another functor or applicative functor is isomorphic to the original. For example, [`Lens'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Lens-39-) is defined as a function polymorphic in a `Functor`:

```
Functor f => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

roughly speaking, such a lens allows to read or manipulate something of type `a` inside `s`, for example a field inside a record (for an introduction to lenses see [this post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-mainstream-programmers_28.html)). If we specialize `f` to `Identity`, we get

```
(a -> Identity a) -> s -> Identity s
```

which is isomorphic to

```
(a -> a) -> s -> s
```

so given an updating function on `a`, return an updating function on `s`. (For completeness: If we specialize `f` to `Const a`, we get `(a -> Const b a) -> s -> Const b s`, which is isomorphic to `(a -> b) -> (s -> b)`, that is, given a reader on `a`, return a reader on `s`.)

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes I work with records whose fields are optional in some contexts (like when parsing the record from JSON) but mandatory in others.

I solve that by parametrizing the record with a functor, and using `Maybe` or `Identity` in each case.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Query f = Query
    {
        _viewName :: String
    ,   _target :: f Server -- Server is some type, it doesn't matter which
    }
    deriving (Generic)
```

The server field is optional when parsing JSON:

```
instance FromJSON (Query Maybe)
```

But then I have a function like

```
withDefaultServer :: Server -> Query Maybe -> Query Identity 
withDefaultServer = undefined
```

that returns a record in which the `_target` field is mandatory.

(This answer doesn't use anything monadic about `Identity`, though.)

Answer (score 10):

One use of it is as a base monad for monad transformer stacks: instead of having to provide two types `Some :: * ->*` and `SomeT :: (* -> *) -> * -> *`, it is enough to provide just a latter by setting `type Some = SomeT Identity`.

Another, somewhat similar use case (but completely detached from the whole monad business) is when you need to refer to tuples: we can say `()` is a nullary tuple, `(a, b)` is a binary tuple, `(a, b, c)` is a ternary tuple, and so on, but what does that leave for the unary case? Saying `a` is a unary tuple for any choice of `a` is often not satisfactory, for example when we are building some typeclass instances like  [`Data.Tuple.Select`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Select.html), some type constructor is needed to act as the unambiguous key. So by adding e.g. `Sel1` instances to `Identity a`, it forces us to distinguish between `(a, b)` (a two-tuple containing an `a` and a `b`), and `Identity (a, b)` (a one-tuple containing a single `(a, b)` value).

(Note that `Data.Tuple.Select` defines its own type called [`OneTuple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/OneTuple-0.2.1/docs/Data-Tuple-OneTuple.html#t:OneTuple) instead of reusing `Identity`, but it is isomorphic to `Identity`—in fact, it's just a rename away—and I think it only exists to avoid a non-`base` dependency.)

Comment: `Identity` is joining base in 4.8 anyway, so that may soon be a historical artifact. `Data.Sequence` uses an internal `Elem` type (also isomorphic to `Identity`) in these ways.

Answer (score 4):

One real use-case is to be a (pure) base of monad transformers stack, e.g.

```
type Reader r = ReaderT r Identity
```